# What does the `&:symb` do?

Tags: ruby, symbols, proc

I've seen an example of how to sort a string. To sort case insensitively:

```
str.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join
#=> "ginrSt"
```

I'm curious about `(&:casecmp)`. I found that for example:

```
arr.map(&:name)
```

is shorthand for

```
arr.map(&:name.to_proc)
```

which is same with

```
arr.map{|el| el.name}
```

I know the `&` (ampersand) tries to convert symbol to proc, and pass it as a block to a method. I do not understand how this would work for `sort` method, which is supposed to compare two values. Would it be as follows?

```
str.chars.sort{|a, b| a.casecmp ;b.casecmp}.join
```

It wouldn't be helpful since `soft` needs a block to return an integer and `casecmp` needs an argument. (Or is it called parameter in that case?) To me, it looks more like this:

```
str.chars.sort{|a, b| a.casecmp(b)}.join
```

How does `&:casecmp` know to take one of `|a, b|` as a caller and the other one as an argument? I wouldn't guess it that it is an option.

Comment: Also: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%26%3A

Comment: Ok I found this:  <br/>
   `class Symbol  
  def to_proc  
    Proc.new do |obj, *args|  
      obj.send self, *args  
    end  
  end  
end`   this I guess why the second parameter from __|a, b|__ was taken as an argument..  still feel anfamiliar with &:symb but reading about that..  <br/> I did try to add  two spaces and <br/> to make line break.. when pressing enter automaticly addscomment.. don't know how to do it

Comment: @mu is to short ..  I was reading the help about comments formating,  
but nowhere I have seen anything  about you must press  
Shift + Enter for linebreak  
which I overuse now..   <br/>  

maybe it depends on browser?  and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

> If more than one parameter is passed to your block, the proc created by Symbol#to_proc uses the additional block parameters as parameters to the method call.

http://phrogz.net/symbol-to-proc-with-multiple-arguments

So, what's really happening is, `sort(&:casecmp)` is converted to:

```
sort {|a,b| a.casecmp(b) }
```

because `sort` takes two parameters.

Comment: Thanks @emaillenin... how do you do line breakes .. when I do 2 spaces on the end and hit enter it adds a coment..

Comment: @Tomasz use shift + enter

Comment: one more time .. THANKS  
I didn't see anything about Shift + Enter when reading about formating comments  

but it work in the comment editing window only.. there is no linebreak after saving it  
and   <br/>  
doesn't help